# I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to <HostName>: The target server failed to respond

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

Problem: I am getting this error message intermittently. I am using httpclient-4.5.2 and PoolingClientConnectionManager

What have I tried:

1. Since some of the posts suggest that this could be due to stale
   connection, I tried cleaning it up from connection manager using

   ```
   connectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();
   connectionManager.closeIdleConnections( idleTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES );
   ```

   This was suggested [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e659)
2. I have also tried HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(
   reqParams, true );

   as in [doc](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setStaleCheckingEnabled(boolean))

I enabled wirelogs but nothing unusual:

```
2017-09-25T02:26:36.109495-07:00  tomcat: [PoolingClientConnectionManager] DEBUG: Connection request: [route: {s}->https://host:443][total kept alive: 3; route allocated: 4 of 20; total allocated: 7 of 800]
2017-09-25T02:26:36.109598-07:00  tomcat: [PoolingClientConnectionManager] DEBUG: Connection leased: [id: 150][route: {s}->https://host:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 4 of 20; total allocated: 7 of 800]
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111038-07:00  tomcat: [DefaultClientConnection] DEBUG: Sending request: GET /api/v1/foo HTTP/1.1
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111152-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "GET /api/v1/foo HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111282-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111373-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=432jnfjwnfkjw3[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111459-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111541-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111635-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "Host: host:443[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111712-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.111789-07:00  tomcat: [Wire] DEBUG:  >> "[\r][\n]"
2017-09-25T02:26:36.112470-07:00  tomcat: [DefaultClientConnection] DEBUG: Connection 0.0.0.0:57992<->10.2.1.1:443 closed
2017-09-25T02:26:36.112633-07:00  tomcat: [DefaultClientConnection] DEBUG: Connection 0.0.0.0:57992<->10.2.1.1:443 closed
2017-09-25T02:26:36.112757-07:00  tomcat: [DefaultRequestDirector] INFO : I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://host:443: The target server failed to respond
```

Even with the above changes, I still see the NoHttpResponse error. What else can I try to find the root cause and fix it?

Comment: Is the server online? Because if it is just `host:443` it will give you that exception because there is no server with that host name

Comment: Yes, the server is online and I have a retry handler. So, when I retry after I get this error, it works fine for the same request on retry. I have scrubbed hostname and urls in the above log messages.

Comment: https://community.jenkins.io/t/extremly-slow-plugin-installs-using-jenkins-plugin-cli/4409   discussion similar to this may be useful to be aware of